# Stumpped trying to pass two parameters from view form to controller

Tags: laravel, forms, parameters, controller

I have a Laravel 6 app and am trying to pass two parameters from my view's form to my controller via a resource route. I can pass one, no problem, but passing two gives the same error:

`Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Admin\SubscriptionsController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected`

I've tried many different arrangements suggested from other posts but none bring the desired result.

Here's my route:

```
Route::resource('subscriptions', 'Admin\SubscriptionsController')
```

Here's my form in my view:

```
 {{ Form::open(['route' => ['admin.subscriptions.update', $plan->id, $coupon_code], 'method' => 'PUT', 'id' => 'role-' . $plan->id, $coupon_code]) }}
                                            Coupon Code: <input type="text" name="coupon_code">
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Here's my controller. It doesn't reach the `dd()` test.

```
public function update($id, $coupon_code)
    {
        dd($coupon_code);
...
```

In the error Whoops! page, I can see the POST DATA that `$coupon_code` is being sent over.

[image: screenshot of POST_DATA]

However, if I remove the `$coupon_code` parameter from the controller (leaving `public function update($id)` ) it functions fine passing $id from form to controller, but I don't get the `$coupon_code` data I need to process. Adding the second parameter bombs it.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the resource controller, it won't allow you to pass additional fields directly to its `update()` route. Instead, you have to override the update route.

Here is how you can do it, Immediately below your resource.

You can add a new route as below:

```php
// web.php
Route::resource('subscriptions', 'Admin\SubscriptionsController')

// Make sure you add name when you are overriding the route
Route::put('subscriptions/{subscription}/{coupon_code?}', 'Admin\SubscriptionsController@update'])->name('admin.subscriptions.update');
```

I believe you won't be sending the coupon code every time so you can add `{coupon_code?}` which becomes optional.

In you controller's `update()` method, make the `coupon_code` optional

```php
public function update($id, $coupon_code = null)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not add a new param for `Route::resource`. If you really want to take 2 params, you should create a new route.

for an example:

```
    Route::resource('subscriptions', 'Admin\SubscriptionsController')->except('update');
    Route::put('/subscriptions/{id}/{coupon_code}', 'Admin\SubscriptionsController@update')->name('subscriptions.update');
```

But I think it's better not using method params. Why not just using input form?

so we can process the coupon code like this:

```
request()->coupon_code;
```